# Add Custom events to Audio tag in HTML 5

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio, custom-event

I am using the Audio tag from HTML5 to render audio on the page.

```
<audio preload="none" id="audioPlayer" controls>
<source src="test.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

I want to fire custom events on play, pause, end of the audio, and at certain intervals of audio as it progresses. I tried all the following methods to bind the events with the audio player but wasn't able to succed.

Approach 1 -

```
var audio = document.getElementById("audioPlayer");

audio.addEventListener('pause', foo());
```

Approach 2 -

```
jQuery("#audioPlayer").bind('play', function () {

    alert("test");           
});
```

Approach 3 -

```
document.getElementById('audioPlayer').addEventListener('play', function () {

    alert("test");
});
```

Approach 4

```
var play_pause = document.getElementById('audioPlayer');
play_pause.addEventListener('play', function () {

    alert("test");
}, false);
```

Comment: Approach 1 wouldn't work because it needs to be `audio.addEventListener('pause', foo);` (changed `foo()`), and as long as there is actually a `foo` function. Your other solutions *should* work fine, but you need to make sure the code is run **after** the `#audioPlayer` element has been rendered/is ready

Comment: Actually I had it as foo(), but then that function is called on page load irrespective of the pause event being fired or not. And it doesn't fire when the actual Pause event occurs.

Answer (score 0):

have you looked at using Web Audio as your API ?  is provides the functionality you need